# Why is $\sum \limits_{i}A_i\dot{x}_i + B = 0$ in general nonintegrable?

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics

Consider the constraint of the form:

> $\sum \limits_{i}A_i\dot{x}_i + B = 0$ where $i=1,2,3$
>
> In general, this equation is nonintegrable.
>
> But if $A_i = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$,$B = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ and $f = f(x_i,t)$
>
> Then the equation can be rewritten as: $\sum \limits_{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\frac{dx_i}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 0$
>
> which is: $\frac{df}{dt} = 0$
>
> and integrated to: $f(x_i,t) -$ constant $ = 0$

Why is it in general nonintegrable?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, as $A_i$ and $B$ can be functions of any variables that are in the constraint, thus we may not be able to integrate the constraint so that we get a constraint consisting of non-$\dot{x}_i$ variables. These differential constraints may not be *exact*.

Look here for example: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/482949/non-integrable-differential-equation-and-non-holonomic-contraints/719438#719438

Comment: Exactness of the differential forms is a sufficient condition for integrability of the system, but it is not necessary. As a very trivial example, consider $\Bbb{R}^2$ with coordinates $(x,y)$ and the differential form $\omega=e^x\,dy$. This $\omega$ is not exact (because $d\omega=e^x\,dx\wedge dy\neq 0$), but this is integrable because $\omega=e^x\,dy=0\implies dy=0$, which can be integrated to give the lines $y=\text{const}$ . What we've done here is notice that $e^{-x}$ is an *integrating factor* (something which you multiply $\omega$ to make it exact).

Comment: The general theorem for necessary and sufficient conditions regarding complete integrability of a system of linearly independent differential 1-forms is given by Frobenius' theorem. For the case of a single nowhere-vanishing 1-form $\omega$, the Frobenius condition is that $d\omega\wedge \omega=0$ (this is satisfied by $\omega=e^x\,dy$). Also, for the example in your link, Frobenius does all the work as well. There, $\omega=dx-a\sin\theta\,d\phi$, so $d\omega\wedge \omega=-a\cos\theta\,d\theta\wedge d\phi\wedge dx$ which is not the zero $3$-form, so the constraint is not integrable.